# C# - Byte array from SecureString

Tags: c#, encryption

I want to programm an Password database (im not going to use it, its a school project), therefore I need an encryptor, to encrypt the passwords, so I can "securly" save them in my db. But because I dont want the Master Password, to be saved as Plaintext in Memory, I want to use SecureString. After a bit of trying out I cant get it to really work. I found a way to get the bytes from the SecureString into a byte Array, which I need to encrypt, but every second entry of the Array is 0.

This is the Code where I try to get the Bytes from the SecureString

```cs
unsafe
            {
                IntPtr unmanagedBytes = Marshal.SecureStringToGlobalAllocUnicode(password);
                byte[] bValue = null;
                try
                {
                    byte* byteArray = (byte*)unmanagedBytes.ToPointer();

                    // Find the end of the string
                    byte* pEnd = byteArray;
                    char c = '\0';
                    do
                    {
                        byte b1 = *pEnd++;
                        byte b2 = *pEnd++;
                        c = '\0';
                        c = (char)(b1 << 8);
                        c += (char)b2;
                    } while (c != '\0');

                    // Length is effectively the difference here (note we're 2 past end) 
                    int length = (int)((pEnd - byteArray) - 2);
                    bValue = new byte[length];
                    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                    {
                        // Work with data in byte array as necessary, via pointers, here
                        bValue[i] = *(byteArray + i);
                        Console.WriteLine(*(byteArray + i));

                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(length);
                    key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(bValue, salt, 50000);

                    Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(bValue));

                }
                finally
                {
                    // This will completely remove the data from memory
                    Marshal.ZeroFreeGlobalAllocUnicode(unmanagedBytes);
                }
            }
```

And this is the Output I get. (Debug Output, I implemented to see why I cant decrypt the password after encrypting)

```
116
0
101
0
115
0
116
0
8
74-00-65-00-73-00-74-00
```

The Password is "test".

The encrypted Password from this in base64 (I am using Base64 to save it in my db) is "xYLqVBBnaKPrryR9ozLiWA=="

And the randomly generated Salt in base64 is "8MDgaz3lPFrdEoueg8bp0J2Vdu1eXGbukmJkztljE54="

If there is a better way, to securly hold the Master Password in Memory, so you only need to login, once you start the Program, please let me know.

Comment: [Don't bother with `SecureString`](https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0001.md)

Comment: And what would be an alternative to SecureString? I really dont want the master Password to just be in Memory the whole time

Comment: Try using OAuth: https://oauth.net/code/dotnet/

Comment: Why do you need to store the password itself in memory? If you're building the identity provider, you should be able to only store a hash of the password in memory.

Comment: My idea was to have the db with the encrypted passwords and you use the Master password to decrypt the login passwords, is this an incorrect way of doing that?

Comment: You don't need to store the encrypted passwords. What you do is to store a salted hash of the password in the database. Then when you need to check if another user-entered password is correct, you compute the salted hash for that password and compare the *hash* to the salted hash stored for that user in the database.

Comment: A good hash to use for passwords is BCrypt. Sample project (not mine): https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/475262/UseplusBCryptplustoplusHashplusYourplusPasswords

Comment: Yeah sorry I porably said wrong what I meant. I want to programm something like Lastpass or Bitwarden. So I do need to be able to decrypt the passwords again :)

Comment: Just comparing the hashes wont work for that. And my Problem is that I dont want the user to have to sign in into the Programm everytime they want to get a password, thats Why I want to save it in Memory to use later, but I dont want it in plaintext because itll be there as long as you have the Programm running

Comment: Ah I see! That's somewhat different.

Comment: How are you going to display the password to the user? I imagine that you'll use some windows control. When you do that, the password would be completely exposed to any processes that could access the window controls in the application. It's going to be much easier for an attacker to just scrape text off the windows controls than to try to find transient strings in memory.

Comment: Yeah I guess thats true. So I just shouldnt bother with trying to hide it better?

Comment: If an attacker has the permissions to read memory of a user process, then they likely also have the rights to log all keystrokes and hook windows messages, so I do think that SecureString isn't going to buy you a significant increase in security.